# Function that adds all the numbers in the sequence, except the numbers between 6 and 9

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break

I need a help to understand how this function is working. Purpose of this function is to sum  all the numbers in the sequence, except the numbers which are in array between 6 and 9, they should be skipped, and to continue to sum numbers which are after number 9 in raw.

For this example [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 2, 9, 1]  results is 10, skip all numbers which are in between 6 and 9 in list.

```
def addition_except_6to9(arr):
    total = 0
    add = True
      for num in arr:
        while add:
            if num != 6:
                total += num
                break
            else:
                add = False
        while not add:
            if num != 9:
                break
            else:
                add = True
                break
     return total
```

How I understand,
First while is executed until number is 6, than first while is break, and go
to beginning of top for loop. Than it takes next number, check first while,
condition is false, than it will go to else of first while and set variable
add to false.

Than takes next number from array, check second while, for numbers different
of nine,  if condition will be true and it will break it, and go on top for
loop, takes next number...until if condition in second while is false for
number = 9, than go to else branch, and set variable add to true, and
continue from top  for loop, to add number which are in array after nine.

I am not quite sure if this function is working on this way.
Why we need break in first while?

Comment: You should use `if` instead of `while`, and no need for break. Also the second `while` can become an `else`.

Comment: [x for x in ml if x not in range(6,10)] where ml is your list.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for quick answers. I made simpler func, based on @tobmei05 hint: '''def summer_69(arr):
    
    return sum([x for x in arr if x not in range(6,10)]) '''

I tested this func, it works for simpler example, but in more complex case does not work. In case below result is 12, and should be 10:
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 2, 9, 1])
12

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
def addition_except_6to9(arr):
    return sum([x for x in arr if not 9 > x > 6])
```

it's sum up all elements except elements between 9 and 6(including 6 and 9) if you want to exclude them then use `return sum([x for x in arr if not 9 >= x >= 6])`

**Update**
If i understand you correctly

```
def addition_except_6to9(arr):
    f6 = arr.index(6)
    l9 = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(arr)))[9]
    ls = [x for x in arr if not(9 >= x >= 6) and not(l9 >= arr.index(x) >= f6)]
    return sum(ls)
```

now with `arr = [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 2, 9, 9, 1]` output is `10` not `12`

Comment: Hi @Ali Aref just additional explanation of purpose of func, it should skip all number which are in list between 6 and 9, but not necessarily to be bigger or lower. Should skip also 2 o3 if they are in between. I wrote example in original question up.

Comment: thanks @Ali Aref, I got error ' name a is not defined'. Advanced solution, difficult for me to understand it.  Is it possible to explain it a bit?  How is l9 defined?  this part will skip all elemtns in list between 6 and 9:  ''' not(l9 >= arr.index(x) >= f6)?'''

Comment: @ddt sure the `l9` defines the index of last 9 item in arr, `f6` is the first 6 element in arr.. now check it out, error solved(miss spell).